# How can I create a simple UDP client-server-communication in Java?

Tags: java, networking, udp, client-server

Where can I find details on UDP in Java and how is a basic UDP communcation established?

Answer (score 5):

[This page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html) provides detailed information on how to create a UPD server and client.

In essence, you create a **server** like this:

```
// Setup the socket
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(12345);

// Receive a packet
byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
socket.receive(packet);

// Do something with the data in the buffer
// and if necessary receive more packets

// Close the socket
socket.close();
```

On the **client** side, you can then send a packet like this:

```
// Create a socket
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();

// Create a buffer and fill it with your data
byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
...

// Send the packet
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, address, 12345);
socket.send(packet);

// Close the socket
socket.close();
```